# Distributing list items to variables in python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm looking for a way to distribute items in a list into individual variables. The point of this is to display individual items as text objects in Blender. Here's what I have so far, but I know there's gotta be a more efficient way to go about doing this.

```
file = open('lyrics.conf')
data = file.read()
file.close()
b = data.split('/')
v = len(b)

if v >= 1:
  v1 = b[0]
if v >= 2:
  v2 = b[1]
if v >= 3:
  v3 = b[2]
if v >= 4:
  v4 = b[3]
if v >= 5:
  v5 = b[4]
if v >= 6:
  v6 = b[5]
if v >= 7:
  v7 = b[6]
if v >= 8:
  v8 = b[7]
if v >= 9:
  v9 = b[8]
if v >= 10:
  v10 = b[9]
```

Comment: `I'm looking for a way to distribute items in a list into individual variables` I can't think of a single legitimate reason for doing this. Tell us what you're trying to accomplish and we can show you a correct way of doing this. What if you had 9000 elements in a list?

Comment: Is this strictly necessary? It's not a very pythonic way to do such a thing. If you tell us more about how you use v1...v10 later we might be able to find you an alternative.

Comment: Well what I'm trying to do is take song lyrics and make 3d text objects in Blender out of each individual verse. Each verse is going to be a separate object in Blender and distributed in a random place in 3d space.

Comment: So tell us why you need to assign each of the array indecis to a variable?

Comment: Still don't see why it is easier for you to use v9 instead of b[8]

Comment: @olskeevi -- now that I know what you want to do, I have to say without reservation that a simple list is by far the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process a list of verses, verse by verse:

```
with open('lyrics.conf') as f:
    data = file.read()
verses = data.split('/')
def build_blender_object(verse):
  # Put meaningful code here
  pass
blender_objects = [build_blender_object(v) for v in verses]
```

Then do whatever you want with the blender objects. If the position in the list matters, then you can use enumerate() to associate an index with each blender object.

Answer (score 6):

if you really want individual variables, at some point you have at least to do an unpacking like `v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10 = some_list`

but why would you want to do this? if something is a collection/list of things, it is best represented as such.

Comment: +1 for a solution that answers the question asked, not that I think it should be done this way in general.

Comment: well, to be fair, (s)he still has to check the length. we could get really dirty by using eval: `eval(",".join("v"+i for i in range(len(b)))+"=b")` or something ugly like that.

Comment: No reason to use eval, see my answer. Though it's just as hacky.

Answer (score 5):

With `b` you already have an easily accessible list of the items you want. Just access them, when you need them at their indices `b[0], b[1], ...`. Populating the namespace with too many variables, whose values can, without major problems, be stored in a container, is a design flaw (in my eyes).

---

Here's a way to inject new variables into the current modules namespace, but it's *evil*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

somelist = range(10)

for i, item in enumerate(somelist):
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'v{0}'.format(i), item)

print v1 + v2
# => 3

print v1 * v2 * v3 * v4 * v5 * v6 - v7 * v8 - v9 + 11
# => ...
```

Comment: +1: Instead of `v1`, `v2`, you use `b[0]` and `b[1]`.  Two extra characters.  That's the way the language works.

Comment: @flying sheep: You got a point, but `setattr` and family are powerful and useful. It shouldn't be used in this case, though. Here's your oneline version: `from sys import modules as _;[setattr(_[__name__],'v%s'%e,e) for i,e in enumerate(range(10))];print v1 + v2`

Comment: thanks! i know that setattr is useful; however here it’s just a hack. and hacks should look loke perl. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Having these v1..10 variables seems like a code smell to me, but you can try this

```
try:
  v1 = b[0]
  v2 = b[1]
  v3 = b[2]
  v4 = b[3]
  v5 = b[4]
  v6 = b[5]
  v7 = b[6]
  v8 = b[7]
  v9 = b[8]
  v10 = b[9]
except IndexError:
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun

```
b = "Some text/ with a / slash / character".split('/')
for i in range(len(b)):
    globals()['v' + str(i + 1)] = b[i]
```

Comment: i tried it, but it doesn’t seem to work. luckily, i would say; it’s horrible. (that’s a compliment :))

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable for the variables to exist and be set to None?

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10 = (b+[None]*10)[:10]
```

or

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10 = b+[None]*(10-len(b))
```