# Python. Cannot place list items into individual variables. When I do, the variable contains the whole list items

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
def nextPage():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('xyz.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
   

    c.execute("INSERT INTO persons VALUES (?,?)",(text.get(),text1.get()))
        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def submit():     
    conn = sqlite3.connect('xyz.db')
    c =conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persons(
        name1 TEXT,
        name2 TEXT)''')        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def query():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('xyz.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM persons')

    records = c.fetchall()
    print(records[0])
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
ws = Tk()
ws.geometry('770x400')
ws.title('PythonGuides')

a = Label(ws ,text = "Name").grid(row = 1,column = 0)
b = Label(ws ,text = "Name of Spouse or CP, if applicable").grid(row = 2,column = 0)
text = Entry(ws)
text.grid(row = 1 , column = 1)

text1 = Entry(ws)
text1.grid(row = 2 , column = 1)

btn = ttk.Button(ws ,text="Submit", command = submit).grid(row=4,column=0)

Button(
    ws, 
    text="Next Page", command=nextPage).grid(row = 5,column = 10)

query()

ws.mainloop

#OUTPUT
#('JOHN', '')
```

I am working on a project using Tkinter and sqlite. Even thou I wanted to print only the 1st item from the list, the whole list was outputted. I want to place the items into individual variables, but each time, the whole list gets stored into a variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Result of `fetchall()` is a *list* of *tuple*.  So `records[0]` is the first record of the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distributing list items to variables in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869391/distributing-list-items-to-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is the line `records = c.fetchall()`. `fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, where each tuple is a row from the database. So when you then `print(records[0])`, you're printing the entire first tuple.

To troubleshoot, try `print(records)`, to print the entire list `records`, and see what that one looks like. You can then adjust the indexing of your `print` function to print only the exact stuff you wantt to print.

Answer (score 1):

```
records = c.fetchall()
print(records[0])
```

The value stored into `records` is a `list` of `tuple`s, so `records[0]` is a `tuple`.

In Python `tuple`s are iterables, so that are indexed and are accessibles like lists:

```
print(records[0][0])
```